# EPPLus - Excel column names not working

Tags: c#, epplus, epplus-4

**Question:** How Can we add `ws.Cells["AA"].Value = "MyColumn";` as a column name to Excel worksheet

Following works until column `Z1`. But I have more columns after `Z` column. So, if I add `ws.Cells["AA"].Value = "MyColumn";`, following does not work.:

```
ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Number";
ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "First Name";
ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Last Name";
ws.Cells["D1"].Value = "Country";
....
....
ws.Cells["Z1"].Value = "Country";
ws.Cells["AA"].Value = "MyColumn";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the row number?

`ws.Cells["AA1"].Value = "MyColumn";`

Comment: Thank you for quick response and pointing out my mistake. It works now.